# dump contents of script to stdout

Tags: bash

If I have something in the bash hash, on the $PATH, is there a way to dump the contents of that script?

e.g. if I do:

```
$ type ores_git_push
```

I get:

> `ores_git_push is hashed (/usr/local/bin/ores_git_push)`

is there a way to get the contents of the script?

if I do:

```
$ type -a ores_git_push
```

I get:

> ```
> ores_git_push is /Users/oleg/.nvm/versions/node/v10.10.0/bin/ores_git_push
> ores_git_push is /usr/local/bin/ores_git_push
> ```

so worse case scenario I guess I could try to parse the results from `type -a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cat "$(type -p ores_git_push)"
```

Answer (score 1):

What about the good old cat command?

```
cat /usr/local/bin/ores_git_push
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why the hash would matter, but you could do:

```
cat $(which ores_git_push)
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249/117549